# Place order using Magento Rest API - Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, api, guest-checkout

Magento 2 API docs

1. http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/
2. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html

I am trying to place an order using magento 2 REST API. What i have done so far is given below,

1. Created an empty cart(`quoteCartManagementV1: /V1/carts`)
2. Added item to my cart(`quoteCartItemRepositoryV1: /V1/carts/mine/items`)
3. Assign billing and shipping info to my cart(`checkoutShippingInformationManagementV1 /V1/carts/{cartid}/shipping-information`)
4. Checking out using the cart I created above(`quoteCartManagementV1: /V1/carts/{cartid}/order`)

I have performed first three of the above four steps successfully, but while performing step no. 4 I am getting the following response from magento 2 REST API,

```
{"message":"Please enter a customer email."}
```

My Request against this response was,

```
{"paymentMethod":{"method":"checkmo"}}
```

Is there anything wrong in my work flow? Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Get Customer Token**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?
username=aditya.shah@test.com&password=test@123
```

- `method : POST`

---

**2. Get Cart ID (Quote ID) - using customer id.**

> This will return quote id, which will be used for placing an order.

```
http://magento-host/rest/V1/carts/mine
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

---

**3. Add Configurable product in cart.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "HKrh15hc", <product SKU>
    "qty": 5,
    "quote_id": "75", <Quote ID - Cart ID [see. step 2]>
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 49
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 168
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

> Now, this will save your configurable product in your cart.

---

**4. Get & put Shipping Information.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
    "addressInformation": {
        "shippingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "221,Baker-street (e)"
            ],
            "company": "Lumos",
            "telephone": "12345678",
            "postcode": "400001",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Aditya",
            "lastname": "Shah",
            "email": "Aditya@Shah.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH",
            "sameAsBilling": 1
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "221,Baker-street (e)"
            ],
            "company": "Lumos",
            "telephone": "12345678",
            "postcode": "4000001",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Aditya",
            "lastname": "Shah",
            "email": "Aditya@Shah.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH"
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
    }
}
```

---

**5. Get payment method.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/75/payment-methods
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

---

**6. Place an order.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/order
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "checkmo"
    }
}
```

**And finally, this will return order ID, which you just placed!**

Comment: how can we use default address ?

Comment: @aditya-shah we get the order IDs but sometimes we get blank Order IDs we have no idea why it's happening. Ever come across this kind of issue ?